# I think my 1and 1 server reinstalled incorrectly, not showing correct HDD space

Tags: linux, 1and1

Hay, the other day i order a new 1 and 1 [dedicated server](https://order.1and1.co.uk/xml/order/ServerPremiumQuadCoreL;jsessionid=7F3969FA572FBC3B2D957AB997BC2685.TCpfix154a?ac=OM.UK.UKb65K19303T7073a).

However, by default it came with a small business panel software, whereas we wanted a full version of Plesk10.

So we reimaged the server and sucessfully installed plesk 10. This seemed to work fine, however if i head over to System statistics and view the HDD. It looks a little odd.

```
name                  total         used          available
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr  4 086.00 MB   1 091.35 MB   2 994.65 MB
/dev/md1              3 759.94 MB   336.87 MB     3 423.07 MB
```

Any ideas? It's as if my 750gb HDD isn't being shown.

Comment: Here's a more detialed look at the table.
http://i.imgur.com/uoCzC.png

Comment: Call 1and1 customer support.

Answer (score 1):

... might be best to ask 1&1 customer support for help...